# Apply arithmetic calculations on specific rows of a large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, bigdata

Suppose that we have a data-frame (`df`) with a high number of rows (1600000X4). Also, we have a list of lists such as this one:

```
inx = [[1,2],[4,5], [8,9,10], [15,16]]
```

We need to calculate average of first and third columns of this data-frame and median of second and fourth columns for every list in `inx`. For example, for the first list of `inx`, we should do this for first and second rows and replace all these rows with a new row which contains the output of these calculations. What is the fastest way to do this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3, 3], [4, 5, 6, 1], [7, 8, 9, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  3
1  4  5  6  1
2  7  8  9  3
3  1  1  1  1
```

The output for just the first list inside of `inx` (`[1,2]`) will be something like this:

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  3
1  5.5  6.5  7.5  2
3  1  1  1  1
```

As you can see, we don't change first row (`0`), because it's not in the main list. After that, we're going to do the same for `[4,5]`. We don't change anything in row 3 because it's not in the list too. `inx` is a large list of lists (more than 100000 elements).

Comment: can you give us an example of the dataframe and an example of the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: NEW APPROACH AVOIDING LOOPS**

Here below you find an approach relying on pandas and avoiding loops.

After generating some fake data with the same size of yours, I basically create list of indexes from your inx list of rows; i.e., with your inx being:

```
[[2,3], [5,6,7], [10,11], ...]
```

the created list is:

```
[[1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3],...]
```

After that, this list is flattened and added to the original dataframe to mark various groups of rows to operate on.
After proper calculations, the resulting dataframe is joined back with original rows which don't need calculations (in my example above, rows: [0, 1, 4, 8, 9, ...]).
You find more comments in the code.

At the end of the answer I leave also my previous approach for the records.
On my box, the old algo involving a loop take more than 18 minutes... unbearable!
Using pandas only, it takes less than half second!! Pandas is great!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

# Prepare some fake data to test
data = np.random.randint(0, 9, size=(160000, 4))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

inxl = random.sample(range(1, 160000), 140000)
inxl.sort()

inx=[]
while len(inxl) > 3:
    i = random.randint(2,3)
    l = inxl[0:i]
    inx.append(l)
    inxl = inxl[i:]
inx.append(inxl)



# flatten inx (used below)
flat_inx = [item for sublist in inx for item in sublist]
# for each element (list) in inx create equivalent list (same length)
# of increasing ints. They'll be used to group corresponding rows
gr=[len(sublist) for sublist in inx]
t = list(zip(gr, range(1, len(inx)+1)))

group_list = [a*[b] for (a,b) in t]

# the groups are flatten either
flat_group_list = [item for sublist in group_list for item in sublist]

# create a new dataframe to mark rows to group retaining 
# original index for each row
df_groups = pd.DataFrame({'groups': flat_group_list}, index=flat_inx)
# and join the group dataframe to the original df
df['groups'] = df_groups
# rows not belonging to a group are marked with 0
df['groups']=df['groups'].fillna(0)

# save rows not belonging to a group for later
df_untouched = df[df['groups'] == 0]
df_untouched = df_untouched.drop('groups', axis=1)

# new dataframe containg only rows belonging to a group
df_to_operate = df[df['groups']>0]
df_to_operate = df_to_operate.assign(ind=df_to_operate.index)

# at last, we group the rows according to original inx
df_grouped = df_to_operate.groupby('groups')

# calculate mean and median
# for each group we retain the index of first row of group
df_operated =df_grouped.agg({'a' : 'mean',
                             'b' : 'median',
                             'c' : 'mean',
                             'd' : 'median',
                             'ind': 'first'})

# set correct index on dataframe
df_operated=df_operated.set_index('ind')

# finally, join the previous dataframe with saved
# dataframe of rows which don't need calcullations
df_final = df_operated.combine_first(df_untouched)
```

**OLD ALGO, TOO SLOW FOR SO MUCH DATA**

This algo involving a loop, though giving a correct result, takes to long for such a big amount of data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3, 3], [4, 5, 6, 1], [7, 8, 9, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

inx = [[1,2]]

for l in inx:
    means=df.iloc[l][['a', 'c']].mean()
    medians=df.iloc[l][['b', 'd']].median()
    df.iloc[l[0]]=pd.DataFrame([means, medians]).fillna(method='bfill').iloc[0]
    df.drop(index=l[1:], inplace=True)
```

Comment: I implemented this structure before but because of size of data-frame ,it's very slow. I'm searching for a faster way.

Comment: I checked different part of about code. I think the main problem is the loop. If we find a way to remove it, It'll significantly improve the speed. Also, `inx` is a large list of lists (more than 100000 elements).

Comment: Ok, @user2991243... so you got me caught into this, so I tested my previous approach with fake data the size of yours. The time taken on my box is more than 18 minutes!! So I took a different path and you can read above the outcome. Managing to use pandas to do the tough work, it takes less than half second! I still cannot believe it! Please, let me know how it works for you.